# Facebook Messager Plugin

Tags: plugins, functions, wp-admin, templates

I deregister Wordpress's default jquery and register the latest jquery. The problem I faced with the Facebook Messenger plugin relied on Wordpress's default to function. Also when I hashed out the deregister and register preference jquery in functions.php the plugin works.

So my question is should I use Facebook Messenger plugin? and how can I force the plugin to use my jquery preference version?

Comment: You shouldn’t deregister WP jQuery - all plugins assume that this is the version that is used...